# R Combine very large list of data tables into one data.table

Tags: r, memory, data.table, out-of-memory

I have a very large list of 13 data.tables (~11.1 Gb total). I have 16Gb of RAM. With the list loaded into memory I have 5 GB of RAM left.

I need to combine these into a single `data.table`. I would prefer to use `data.table::rbindlist` if possible due to its `fill = TRUE` parameter (some of my data.tables have columns the others do not have - I need those filled with NA).

The problem is this is requiring more than 5 GB of RAM to complete and I am unable to combine the list. It would seem like I already have the data loaded into memory and a combined `data.table` wouldn't be any bigger. I just need to figure out if there's a way to complete the operation without having to copy the entire list into memory (occupying 22GB of RAM) to perform the `rbindlist`.

In order to make this list in the first place, I am running an `lapply` that looks like:

```
  df <- lapply(fs::dir_ls(dir), function(file) {
     clean_data(file)
  })
```

I am taking a list of `.csv` files and converting them to clean data.tables via `lapply`, which is how I end up with a list.

`purrr::map_dfr` does not seem to work and neither does just wrapping the `lapply` in `rbindlist`.

Comment: Join in pairs and continue removing the binded elements!

Comment: What format are the files? (csv, rda, rds, feather, disk-frame, ...)

Comment: They are tab-separated value files.

Comment: If you can make sure the column names for each file all exist and are in the same order, then outside of R, `{ cat file1.tsv ; grep -v "column_name_in_header_only" file2.tsv file3.tsv file4.tsv ; } > combined.tsv` is pretty fast and as memory efficient as the OS will allow.

Comment: So each file would have to already have all possible columns?

Comment: Try `dt= data.table(); for (f in fnames) dt = rbindlist(list(dt, fread(f)), fill=T)`

Comment: @DylanRussell yes. `/bin/cat` is pretty naive, it doesn't care. If you pre-condition each file so that each has the same number and order of columns, then concatenating the data on the filesystem level is much much more efficient than anything you can do in R

Comment: Another option: `disk.frame`. It uses `data.table` memory-efficient operators including `rbindlist.disk.frame`, which suggests it might be more memory-frugal and useful for you.

Comment: @dww unfortunately that did not work, it ran out of memory to allocate.

Comment: @r2evans what is  grep -v "column_name_in_header_only"?

Comment: `/usr/bin/grep` is a command-line (not-R) tool that work with regular expressions (optionally `-E`xtended or `-P`erl regex extensions) to match lines in files/input-streams. In this case, `-v` is `--invert-match`, so it returns any line that doesn't match that pattern. In this use-case, the row of column names is included in the first file, but you don't want it in any of the other files, so `grep -v` is meant to exclude the first row in each file. There are other ways, such as `for f in file2.tsv file3.tsv file4.tsv; do sed -e 1d $f ; done`, this being more precise in its filtering.

Answer (score 3):

There might be an R-only way of doing this, but one efficient way would be to do this with command-line (not R) tools.

Setup for the sake of this answer:

```r
mt1 <- mtcars[1:3,c(1,2,3)]
mt2 <- mtcars[3:4,c(1,2,4)]
mt3 <- mtcars[5:10,c(1,3,4)]

combined <- rbindlist(list(mt1, mt2, mt3), use.names = TRUE, fill = TRUE)
combined
#      mpg cyl  disp  hp
#  1: 21.0   6 160.0  NA
#  2: 21.0   6 160.0  NA
#  3: 22.8   4 108.0  NA
#  4: 22.8   4    NA  93
#  5: 21.4   6    NA 110
#  6: 18.7  NA 360.0 175
#  7: 18.1  NA 225.0 105
#  8: 14.3  NA 360.0 245
#  9: 24.4  NA 146.7  62
# 10: 22.8  NA 140.8  95
# 11: 19.2  NA 167.6 123

write.table(mt1, "mt1.tsv", row.names = FALSE)
write.table(mt2, "mt2.tsv", row.names = FALSE)
write.table(mt3, "mt3.tsv", row.names = FALSE)
```

Now that we know what the data looks like, let's get the filenames programmatically:

```r
filenames <- list.files(".", pattern = "^mt.*\\.tsv", full.names = TRUE)
filenames
# [1] "./mt1.tsv" "./mt2.tsv" "./mt3.tsv"
```

From here, let's grab the first 1 row from each file (quickly/efficiently, since it's only 1 row each) and `rbindlist` them so that we know what the resulting table should look like. Granted, we don't need to keep any of the actual values, just the columns.

```r
row1s <- rbindlist(lapply(filenames, function(fn) fread(fn, nrows = 1)),
                   use.names = TRUE, fill = TRUE)[0,]
row1s
# Empty data.table (0 rows and 4 cols): mpg,cyl,disp,hp
```

For demonstration here, note that merging this 0-row table with one of the originals renders a consistent schema. (No need to do this with real data unless you want to verify one or two.)

```r
row1s[mt1, on = intersect(names(row1s), names(mt1))]
#     mpg cyl disp hp
# 1: 21.0   6  160 NA
# 2: 21.0   6  160 NA
# 3: 22.8   4  108 NA
row1s[mt2, on = intersect(names(row1s), names(mt2))]
#     mpg cyl disp  hp
# 1: 22.8   4   NA  93
# 2: 21.4   6   NA 110
```

The goal will be to do this for all files programmatically:

```r
# iterate through each file: read, left-join, write
for (fn in filenames) {
  dat <- fread(fn)
  dat <- row1s[dat, on = intersect(names(row1s), names(dat))]
  fwrite(dat, file.path(dirname(fn), paste0("augm_", basename(fn))), sep = "\t")
}

newfilenames <- list.files(".", pattern = "^augm_mt.*\\.tsv$", full.names = TRUE)
newfilenames
# [1] "./augm_mt1.tsv" "./augm_mt2.tsv" "./augm_mt3.tsv"
```

To verify the new files look consistent, look for the double-`\t` (which indicate empty data, i.e. `NA` on import):

```r
# double-\t indicates an empty field
lapply(newfilenames, readLines, n = 2)
# [[1]]
# [1] "mpg\tcyl\tdisp\thp" "21\t6\t160\t"      
# [[2]]
# [1] "mpg\tcyl\tdisp\thp" "22.8\t4\t\t93"     
# [[3]]
# [1] "mpg\tcyl\tdisp\thp" "18.7\t\t360\t175"
```

Now that we have this, let's go to a command-prompt (on windows, git-bash or just windows' bash if you need it). We need `bash` and one of `tail` or `grep`. The goal is that the want the column headers from one of these `augm_mt` files but none of the others.

If we naively concatenate the files, we'll see the header row repeated in the middle of the data ... and with R, this means that every column will be `character`, likely not what you want:

```bash
$ cat augm_mt1.tsv augm_mt2.tsv
mpg     cyl     disp    hp
21      6       160
21      6       160
22.8    4       108
mpg     cyl     disp    hp
22.8    4               93
21.4    6               110
```

Three options to side-step this, depending on what tools you have and how much you trust the contents of your data. (I suggest number 1, `tail`, if you have it, as it is the least-ambiguous.)

1. If you have `tail`, then we can "start at line 2" (skipping line 1) for each file:

   ```bash
   $ cat augm_mt2.tsv
   mpg     cyl     disp    hp
   22.8    4               93
   21.4    6               110

   $ tail -n +2 augm_mt2.tsv
   22.8    4               93
   21.4    6               110
   ```

   If you run this on multiple files, it tends to prepend the filename with each set of tailed lines (try it), we'll suppress that in favor of contiguous lines by adding the `-q` option.
2. If you know that one or more of the column names are *never* seen in the real contents, then you can do one of:

   ```bash
   $ grep -v mpg augm_mt2.tsv
   22.8    4               93
   21.4    6               110

   $ grep -v 'mpg.*cyl.*disp' augm_mt3.tsv
   18.7            360     175
   18.1            225     105
   14.3            360     245
   24.4            146.7   62
   22.8            140.8   95
   19.2            167.6   123
   ```
3. More complicated but should be safer than "hand-written regex" as in number 2:

   ```bash
   $ HDR=$(head -n 1 augm_mt2.tsv)
   $ grep -F "$HDR" -v augm_mt2.tsv
   22.8    4               93
   21.4    6               110
   ```

   (The `-F` means "fixed string", so no regex matching is attempted. This is safest, since something like a period in a column name could pose a potential risk. Remote, but non-zero.)

Whichever way you choose to go, this is how you combine those three files into one mega-file for reading back into R:

```bash
$ { head -n 1 augm_mt1.tsv ; tail -q -n +2 augm_*.tsv ; } > alldata_mt.tsv
```

The `head -n 1` merely outputs the header row only, no data, making it much easier to do `augm_*.tsv` in the next command. (Otherwise we would need to find a way to do everything do all-but-the-first.)

Now we can read this back into R in one command:

```r
fread("alldata_mt.tsv")
#      mpg cyl  disp  hp
#  1: 21.0   6 160.0  NA
#  2: 21.0   6 160.0  NA
#  3: 22.8   4 108.0  NA
#  4: 22.8   4    NA  93
#  5: 21.4   6    NA 110
#  6: 18.7  NA 360.0 175
#  7: 18.1  NA 225.0 105
#  8: 14.3  NA 360.0 245
#  9: 24.4  NA 146.7  62
# 10: 22.8  NA 140.8  95
# 11: 19.2  NA 167.6 123
```

And for validation with this micro-data:

```r
all.equal(fread("alldata_mt.tsv"), combined)
# [1] TRUE
```

---

**Alternative** that leaves intermediate files with no column headers, so we don't have to dance around things:

```r
for (fn in filenames) {
  dat <- fread(fn)
  dat <- row1s[dat, on = intersect(names(row1s), names(dat))]
  fwrite(dat, file.path(dirname(fn), paste0("augm_", basename(fn))), sep = "\t", col.names = FALSE)
}
```

Then in bash:

```bash
$ cat augm_*tsv > alldata2_mt.tsv
```

Then in R again,

```r
fread("alldata2_mt.tsv", header = FALSE)
#       V1 V2    V3  V4
#  1: 21.0  6 160.0  NA
#  2: 21.0  6 160.0  NA
#  3: 22.8  4 108.0  NA
#  4: 22.8  4    NA  93
#  5: 21.4  6    NA 110
#  6: 18.7 NA 360.0 175
#  7: 18.1 NA 225.0 105
#  8: 14.3 NA 360.0 245
#  9: 24.4 NA 146.7  62
# 10: 22.8 NA 140.8  95
# 11: 19.2 NA 167.6 123
```

... and you'll have to know the names to reassign them. This method seems like a little less work (it is), but it does leave the remote possibility that the order of column names is inadvertently changed. The first method above that preserves column names in all of the files preempts that potential mis-step.

Answer (score 1):

Here's an R data.table approach. Similar in concept to @r2evans answer, but using only R, we can start by concatenating all the files into a single csv with all the columns filled in:

First read the column names of all files and create a vector of the unique names

```
library(data.table)
fnames = list.files(pattern = 'dt.+csv')
fcols = lapply(fnames, fread, nrows=0)
fcols = sapply(fcols, names)
fcols = unique(as.vector(fcols))
```

Now add each file's data into a single csv, with missing values replaced with NA. Note that the `remove(fdt); gc()` lines maybe not needed, as fdt gets reassigned and R *should* handle the memory management of this ok for you.  I added them just to make sure that any no longer used memory is freed regulalrly.

```
for (f in fnames) {
  fdt = fread(f)
  fdt[, (setdiff(fcols, names(fdt))) := NA]
  fwrite(fdt[, .SD, .SDcols = fcols], 'all.csv', append = T)
  remove(fdt)
  gc()
}
```

Then we just read in a single file

```
fdt = fread('all.csv')
```

### some dummy reproducible data files

```
set.seed(1)
dt1 = data.table()[, (sample(letters[1:5],3)) := sample(10)]
dt2 = data.table()[, (sample(letters[1:5],3)) := sample(10)]
dt3 = data.table()[, (sample(letters[1:5],3)) := sample(10)]
dt4 = data.table()[, (sample(letters[1:5],3)) := sample(10)]
fwrite(dt1, 'dt1.csv')
fwrite(dt2, 'dt2.csv')
fwrite(dt3, 'dt3.csv')
fwrite(dt4, 'dt4.csv')
remove(dt1, dt2, dt3, dt4)
```